# Comparing 2 Video Cards

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade

I have an older computer and looking to upgrade my video card because I am attempting to do some basic 3D in Photoshop and my current video card does not support hardware acceleration. I have two video cards I am comparing and considering. But it comes down to a few questions I have.

One card is 512MB and the other is 1GB in Memory, does that extra 512 in memory really going to make a difference that it is worth paying extra for (doubles the price).

Basically is the performance improvement going to be noticeable or it might be noticeable or not noticeable at all.

Are there other requirements that I should be looking into? Meaning The 512 Card has this which will make it better (or worse) because...

Thanks for any assistance in helping me understand =>

Please when you say `"But it's twice as fast"` give details and explanations as to how twice as fast is truly better (remember more is not always better)

Note: Both cards have the requirments for 3D in Photoshop which are:

- supports OpenGL, a software and hardware standard that accelerates video processing when working with large or complex images, including 3D.
- has at least 256 MB of RAM.
- has a display driver that supports OpenGL 2.0 and Shader Model 3.0, which the GPU uses to perform rendering effects.

Here are my computer specs along with both video card specs:

**Computer**

```
P4 - 2.8 GHZ - 3GB RAM - AGP Version 3 8x - Windows XP Pro (SP3)
```

**512 Card**

```
Bus Width   64 bit
RAMDAC Speed    400 MHz
Analog Signal   Yes
Digital Signal  Yes
Chipset Manufacturer    NVIDIA
Chipset Model   Geforce 6200
Chipset Line    GeForce
Chipset Series  6
Height  2.7"
Memory Technology   DDR2 SDRAM
Maximum Resolution  2048 x 1536
Length  4.3"
Memory Speed    1064 MHz
Product Model   512-A8-N405-KR
Processor Speed 300 MHz
Standard Memory 512 MB
Host Interface  AGP 8x
API Supported   DirectX 9.0
OpenGL 2.0
Dual RAMDAC Yes
Number of Monitors Supported    2
Cooler Type Passive Cooler
```

**1 GB Card**

```
HDCP Supported  Yes
Bus Width   128 bit
Analog Signal   Yes
Digital Signal  Yes
Chipset Manufacturer    ATI
Chipset Model   3650
Chipset Line    Radeon
Chipset Series  HD 3000
Memory Technology   DDR2 SDRAM
Maximum Resolution  2560 x 1600
Product Model   900284
Processor Speed 725 MHz
Standard Memory 1 GB
Host Interface  AGP 8x
API Supported   DirectX 10.1
Shader Model    4.1
Number of Stream Processors 120
```

Comment: Both the cards are really, really old. Like 4-5 generations old.

Comment: My computer is 4-5 generations old => I must use a AGP card and those are some of the best I could find for the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For exactly this pair I'll say

- Emotional and qualitative assessment: Radeon!!! 6200 is low low-end in 6000 series of NVidia, 3650 wins even NVIDIA GeForce **8600 GT** and NVIDIA GeForce **6800 Ultra** in general rating,  which in turn is much more powerful than ordinary 6200
- Quantitative assessment: for the same memory type (DDR2) Radeon has more speed for memory (TBT!) and GPU and twice the width of the bus (*only the latter* implies a doubled data rate)

Size of Video Memory doesn't play game (I think, but *can not assert*) at all - even 512MB will work on big resolutions.

Check your current PSU and requirements for selected card before buy - AFAIR, Radeon will want additional power and 400W PSU as minimum (I may be wrong)

Comment: If I was looking for a replacement, then stopped on the ATI RADEON HD4650

Comment: Both cards require 300W and my power supply is 480 => Thanks for the information.

Comment: Also from what I could tell both the NVIDIA Cards are PCI-E not AGP. I do not have PCI-E Slot or I would be going with a PCI-E Card =>

Comment: 8600 and 6800 was mention only as *comparison point*, not as replacement